# construct a vector from brackets of integers

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, string-parsing

I was wondering how to do the following efficiently. Given brackets of integers, create a stl vector accordingly?

e.g. given

```
[[-9],[-8,0],[-3,2,5],[6,3,0,-4],[-2,-9,-5,-8,6],[0,-5,0,-2,-1,5],[0,6,-1,-5,-8,6,-5],[-8,-5,-9,-8,-4,-3,-5,7]]
```

then, construct a 2d vector from it.

```
vector<vector <int> > vv;
```

**EDIT:**

1. I do not have latest compiler with c++11, so the way that directly construct like,

   std::vector v({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

   is not what I want.
2. what I currently have in mind is as follows.

   int x1[1]={-9};

   int x2[2]={-8, 0};
       ...

   std::vector v1(x1, x1 + sizeof x1 / sizeof x1[0]);

   std::vector v2(x2, x2 + sizeof x2 / sizeof x2[0]);
       ...

   vv.push_back(v1);

   vv.push_back(v2);
       ...

But this is too tedious, and I have quite a lot of brackets.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How well did it work? What didn't work? Can you elaborate what you consider "efficiently"?

Comment: What do you want in the vector?

Comment: Given that input when? At compile-time to add to the source? At run-time to be parsed?

Comment: replace the `[]` with `{}` and play around.

Comment: @KarthikT No playing around required, works straight off ;)

Comment: @Troy hehe ya.. He has to ensure he has a recentish compiler tho

Comment: Do you want to *parse* such a string and turn it into a vector dynamically or do you just want to find an easy way to make that in code?

Comment: yes. parse the string and construct the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv = {{-9},{-8,0},{-3,2,5},{6,3,0,-4},{-2,-9,-5,-8,6},{0,-5,0,-2,-1,5},{0,6,-1,-5,-8,6,-5},{-8,-5,-9,-8,-4,-3,-5,7}}; 
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df6c791c2d379e8c) (gcc / clang in C++11 mode).